# Netbeans + Ubuntu installed in vmware

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu, vmware

I have Netbeans in Ubuntu and the Ubuntu is installed in VMWare.
I tried to print from 1 to 10000 using println.

It is a very simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Each time the output window will only print from 1 to a random number smaller than 10000. Therefore, I tried to use terminal to execute my program. It will print correctly.
Any idea of this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Call `System.Out.Flush()` after your `for` loop.